# Hwi oauth bundle and Symfony 3.4 Cannot autowire service : How to use hwi/oauth-bundle in symfony 3.4 + FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, fosuserbundle, type-hinting, hwioauthbundle

I'm upgrading an application written in Symfony 2.8.5 to Symfony 3.4

I would like to use hwi/oauth-bundle to keep the oauth Facebook / Google login in Symfony 3.4. (My oauth login was working on Symfony 2.8.5 with 
FOSUserBundle ) 
Now I get this error:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Security\Core\User\OAuthUserProvider": argument "$properties" of method "__construct()" must have a type-hint or be given a value explicitly.
```

This is my UserProviderClass extending FOSUSBUserProvider :

```
namespace App\Security\Core\User;

use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface; 
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseClass;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserChecker;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;

/**
* Class OAuthUserProvider
* @package AppBundle\Security\Core\User
*/
class OAuthUserProvider extends BaseClass {

private $mailer;
private $container;

public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager,array $properties, $mailer, $container) {

    parent::__construct($userManager, $properties);
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

This is my services.yaml:

```
app.provider.oauth:
    class: App\Security\Core\User\OAuthUserProvider
    arguments: ['@fos_user.user_manager',{facebook: 'myFacebookId', google: 'myGoogleId'},'@mailer','@service_container']
```

This is my security.yaml:

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory: { memory: ~ }
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook: "/login/check-facebook"
                google: "/login/check-google"

            failure_path: /login
            use_forward: false
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /connect_check
            #provider: fos_userbundle # is oauth:provider is supported in symfony 3.4 ???
            success_handler: redirect.after.login

            oauth_user_provider:
                service: app.provider.oauth

encoders:
    App\Entity\User\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
```

I really don't understand because in my services.yaml I'm defining all arguments required even properties as an array ...
I guess hwi/oauth-bundle and fos/user-bundle are both not anymore officialy supported in Symfony 3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Security` in your `exclude` value:

```html
# config/services.yaml

services:
    _defaults:
        # ...

     App\:
         resource: '../src/*'
         exclude: '../src/{Entity,Security,Migrations,Tests}'

     App\Controller\:
         resource: '../src/Controller'
         tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
...
```